# Web Pushnotification PUSH API and service worker C# - Not seeing notifcation

Tags: c#, push-notification, push, service-worker

have followed the steps mentioned in the Push code lab Push Notifications site to integrated Push notification in my dot net ``site

1.register Service worker and also was able to see the Subscription on the page.

Subscription:

Step: have down Loaded the C# Library  to  send the Push Notifications and have added  Test Program to test this C#code. i am able to run the code and no Error were shown but i am not seeing any Push Notification in the Chrome Browser( Kept the same Browser tab opened where i have my Site Running / Also closed the browser and Relaunched to see any Notification).In Either case i am not seeing any Notifications

I am not seeing any Error from the Code an

> 

below is the Response from Web pushClient.

{StatusCode: 201, ReasonPhrase: 'Created', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: {   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff   X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN   X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block   Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="39,38,37,36,35"   Cache-Control: max-age=0, private   Date: Wed, 05 Jul 2017 15:59:43 GMT   Location: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/0:1499270383802342%e609af1cf9fd7ecd   Server: GSE   Content-Length: 0   Content-Type: text/plain   Expires: Wed, 05 Jul 2017 15:59:43 GMT }}

```js
 var pushEndpoint = @"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/dKUDjOvvyjg:APA91bF3jr2gsX--KjonylSL_25TfCGG5mVsFZoYgnESYLep2rlWOI6KK1T9Dghr9E8o1e7a0wtOCH2LqmcCV0pjW7ZuDW7wPptJnnXy3XBu4Eo_CX0fLYGqsqy8voU9pFg6eZyaDFab";
            var p256dh = @"BMEI2Zz1LPeFBeBtEZlTV_St0PHb6v_OlldbUoE6wrnnx8ychyz4o7tMt_S_Z0bKQj3vOAS0lMuZRRrgO7-LEGo=";
            var auth = @"hwrfOP0UUevO5UdB6WRIQw==";

            var subject = @"mailto:megan@gmail.com";
            var publicKey = @"BK4ITwwSPZpxelX-oaycWnPuRSnRetbu3QBY4hSm5f1Up24PTrktIrJxRXR9bUIqrGx2YFcDCv48sDwFW50jdmI";
            var privateKey = @"PEW_j759M2Q218O9le3GS8OnejmwlWYI1-LtNAP31bg";

            var subscription = new PushSubscription(pushEndpoint, p256dh, auth);
            var vapidDetails = new VapidDetails(subject, publicKey, privateKey);
            //var gcmAPIKey = @"[your key here]";

            var webPushClient = new WebPushClient();
            try
            {
                webPushClient.SendNotification(subscription, "payload", vapidDetails);
                //webPushClient.SendNotification(subscription, "payload", gcmAPIKey);
            }
            catch (WebPushException exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Http STATUS code" + exception.StatusCode);
            }
```

Comment: Can you post your service worker as well? Looks like the response you're getting is right, so it's probably an issue with how you're handling it on the service worker side.

Comment: 'use strict';
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
    console.log('[Service Worker] Push Received.');
    console.log('[Service Worker] Push had this data: "${event.data.text()}"');
    const title = 'DoorStep  Services';
    const options = {
        body: 'Hurry Up..',
        icon: 'images/bell.jpg',
        badge: 'images/badge.png'
    };
    const notificationPromise = self.registration.showNotification(title, options);
    event.waitUntil(notificationPromise);
});

Comment: above is the Service Worker File:

Comment: one observation i have made is when i connected to my office Internal network it is not showing Push Notifications but when  i connected to my Home Internet Network it is showing  notification. Not sure any Service Worker registration issues or  any Proxy issues while i am in  Work Location Network. any suggestions will be helpful

Comment: Any help on this ?

Comment: can any help be provided  on this

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your service worker source, I think you need to move the showNotification call inside the event.waitUntil call. So something like this:

```
event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, options));
```

However if you're getting notifications on your home network and not your work network, that leads me to believe something on your work network is blocking it.